Equator on astrolabe - how to determine location
I am reading "The Light Ages" by Sebastian Falk. I have a grasp of the main markings on an astrolabe but I am having difficulty understanding how the equator marking was determined on the plate. I understand the following. For a given latitude: zenith = point directly above point of observation, ecliptic= plane containing the orbits of the observed planets of the Solar System, horizon = circular limit to observation if no objects obscuring the view to the horizon. I understand what the earth and celestial equator are, but I don't understand how they correspond to some observable arc, which could then be inscribed on the astrolabe, and what the equator was understood to represent in terrestrial or celestial terms at the time the astrolabe was originally designed and constructed. Any explanations would be appreciated.
